# Why does `bash <command>` fail to run?

Tags: bash

Why does `bash <command>` fail to run?

```
$ bash date
/bin/date: /bin/date: cannot execute binary file

$ /bin/date
Fri Mar 18 05:59:24 EDT 2016

$ bash -c date
Fri Mar 18 06:00:39 EDT 2016
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

From the [manual](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html):

> If arguments remain after option processing, and neither the `-c` nor the `-s` option has been  supplied,  the  first argument  is  assumed to be the name of a file containing shell commands.

So `bash date` means "read the `date` file and execute the shell commands it contains". Assuming there is no `date` file in the current directory, `bash` searches the path and finds `/bin/date` which is a binary rather than a shell script, hence the error.

Answer (score 2):

Without `-c` `bash` tries to run the argument as its script. The `/bin/date` is not a `bash` script, so it fails.